I want to divide the Title section of the Colorbox into 3 equal parts as shown in the image below. The code I am using is below
 That's what we're trying to do.!
Code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\addtolength\topmargin{-27pt} \addtolength\textheight{68pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=0.1cm, outer=1cm, top=2cm,
bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}


 
\begin{document}


\tcbset{colback=white, coltitle=black, colframe=green!55!,fonttitle=\bfseries}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My title]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}


 
 
\end{document}


Instead of dividing the title, you could use overlays to add the square and the stars:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    
\tcbset{  
  enhanced,
  colback=white, 
  coltitle=black, 
  colframe=green!55!,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  halign title=flush center, 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  title=My title,
  overlay={
    \node[anchor=north west,white] at (frame.north west) {$\blacksquare$};
    \node[anchor=north east,red] at (frame.north east) {$\bigstar\bigstar\bigstar$};
  }
]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

 
\end{document}




For the star, I use bbding package and a command \repeatstar
For the square, I use \vrule in framebox

Code
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/732471/i-want-to-divide-the-title-section-of-the-colorbox-into-3-equal-parts-as-shown-i
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bbding}% for five star

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\repeatstar}{ O{black} m }
{
  % #1, color star
  % #2, number of star
    \normalfont% warning U/ding/bx/n undefined 
    \color_select:n {#1}
    \prg_replicate:nn {#2} {\raisebox{-0.3ex}{\FiveStar}} 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mysquare}{
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% 3pt by default
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.8pt}% 0.2 by default
  \framebox{\color{white}\vrule height 8pt width 8pt}}

\NewTColorBox{mybox}{ O{black} m m }
  {
    % #1, color star
    % #2, the title
    % #3, number of star
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=green!55!,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=%
      {\mysquare\hfill #2\hfill\repeatstar[#1]{#3}}
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[red!70!black]{My title}{3}
  This is a tcolorbox.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{\parbox{5cm}{long title long title long title long title}}{2}
  This is a tcolorbox.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}


